# No table found SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have read almost all the answer from this platform but can not get the answer

I have created sqlLite database with name `User_Info` Sequelize is  connected with the database and i have a model right below

**Sequelize**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Option 1: Passing parameters separately
const sqlLIte = new Sequelize('User_Info', '', '', {
    // sqlite! now!
    dialect: 'sqlite',

    // the storage engine for sqlite
    storage: '../User_Info'
  })

  //authenticating the database connection
  sqlLIte
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

  module.exports = sqlLIte
```

**MODEL**

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sqlLIte = require('./sequelize')

const userModel = sqlLIte.define('User', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    contact: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,

    // define the table's name
    tableName: 'User',
    timestamps: false
})

userModel.findAll().then(res=>{console.log(res)}).catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
module.exports = userModel
```

**problem is** but Sequelize `findAll` function is throwing the no such table but when i use sqlLite to fetch the data it bring the data from database but Sequelize isn't working.

Comment: try to get SQL from findAll and see if it;s right or not

Comment: i didn't get you point @Anatoly

Comment: just set logging: true in sequelize options and look at console what SQL queries sequelize executes

Comment: @Anatoly   i have updated the question as you said and the query is SELECT `name`, `email`, `password`, `contact` FROM `User` AS `User` but still **No such table : User **

Comment: So if you execute this query manually it will work just fine?

Comment: @Anatoly yes manually it is working fine but sequelize isn't working

Comment: May it be related to the name of the table? Since `user` is usually a keyword in many databases.